# search-container-row by multiple PK value of the keyProperty

Tags: liferay, portlet, portal

I have a portlet that has multi PK fields in the service.xml.
I have change some classes and JSPs to set and get the PKs values and save and load the records, but I cant view the registered records on the `view.jsp` page because I cant set the value of the `keyProperty` attribute of the `search-container-row`.
My portlet with `AppB` name has the `AppBPK` class that has the `AppBPK(long ID1, long ID2)` constructor.
How can I set the `keyProperty` attribute to view the records?

Comment: could you provide more code please?